# grails app failing to run (postgresql driver issue)

Tags: macos, postgresql, grails, groovy

I've recently started working on a Grails application, but every time I try to run it simply crashes. This seems to be the error that is triggering it:

```
Caused by ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
->>  59 | findClass in org.grails.plugins.tomcat.ParentDelegatingClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   306 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   247 | loadClass in     ''
|   1420 | createConnectionFactory in org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource
|   1371 | createDataSource in     ''
|   1044 | getConnection in     ''
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   695 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

I have postgresql included in my dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy:

```
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1102-jdbc41'
```

It's also shown in my list of dependencies when I generate a list through the terminal.

The application set-up is Grails 2.2.4, which I'm running using SDK. Groovy version is 2.0.8 and Java environment oracle64-1.7.0.79 (I'm also running postgres.app (port 5432). I'm also using OSX 10.11.5 in case that's useful.

Any pointers or directions to pursue would be great as I really feel like I'm hitting my head against a wall at this point!

Comment: is this from the command line?

Comment: Hi Tim,

Yes it's all from the command line (with the exception of the line of code from my BuildConfig.groovy).